# Swift Unit Testing and AVFoundation: how to test for the presence/absence of a valid capture device?

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, tdd, avfoundation

I'm coding an app that uses the camera(s) of the device, and I'm trying my hand at TDD seriously for the first time.

I am trying to test this function, specifically:

```
func startRunning(cameraPosition: CameraPosition) -> CaptureSessionPreview?
```

where `CameraPosition` is an enum (front and back cases) and `CaptureSessionPreview` is a protocol that defines an object/struct that has a video layer (like `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`) to display.

I'd like to write tests to define what will happen when there is or isn't a specific camera (front or rear) available.

I'm using a mock `AVCaptureDevice` that i can init with a position and injecting it to test for the presence or absence of a device, but I also want to test that I can indeed init an `AVCaptureSession` with the camera as input (otherwise I should still get an error).

I'm struggling trying to init `AVCaptureDeviceInput` with a valid mock (it always returns nil for me). Is this even the best way to test it? Help?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I am trying to write tests for using AVCaptureSession and Vision for barcode reading but not sure where to start mocking it

Comment: I didn't, not to my liking at least, but my solution looks much different now anyway

Comment: @simoneconnola: Can you please help me on how you are mocking AVCaptureDevice? I am using Cuckoo.